# PreTranslateMessage in C# for hosted MFC window

Tags: c#, mfc, interop, hosting, windows-messages

We developped an MFC application where the main window was implemented in a DLL.  In an attempt to revamp it, we are thinking of changing this to a WPF-application where the "old" native window gets rehosted in a Wpf-Window.  So far so good.

However, our old MFC application trapped some messages at the application level (ex: preventing mouse-clicks or keyboard inputs).  To rehost the MFC-window inside the WPF-application, we need a way to catch these from the WPF-application and ask the old MFC-window to pre-translate them...

Is this possible at all?

I was thinking of rehosting the MFC window in a HwndHost, then add a message hook.  The code in my bridging CLR-DLL looks like this (and doesn't achieve what I want):

```
MyHwndHost ^handle = gcnew MyHwndHost(pContentWnd);
handle->MessageHook += gcnew HwndSourceHook(&CVSimCoreNat::ControlMsgFilter);
```

Can anyone help?